# Is there a name for "zero measure": $\phi(A)=0$ for all set $A$

Tags: measure-theory

I don't want to reinvent new names when writing a paper. I want to ask if there is already a name for a "zero measure", or "null measure", which makes every measurable set measure zero.

Comment: It should be called the [trivial measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_measure#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20in%20measure,for%20all%20A%20in%20%CE%A3.).